# AttributeError: 'BarContainer' object has no attribute 'get_height'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to break the `yaxis` of the `MWE` below in the range `[40, 90]`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 2
ind = np.arange(n)  
width = 0.45       

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

yvals = [10, 20]
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, yvals, width, color='r')
zvals = [15,35]
rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, zvals, width, color='g')

ax.set_ylim([0, 100])

ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xticks(ind+width/2)

ax.set_xticklabels( ('A', 'B') )
ax.legend( (rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('M', 'N') )

def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        h = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*h, '%{}'.format(int(h)),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

plt.show()
```

So, using `Brokenaxes` module, I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from brokenaxes import brokenaxes

N = 2
ind = np.arange(N)  
width = 0.45       

fig = plt.figure()

baxes = brokenaxes(ylims=((0,40),(90,100)), hspace=.05)

yvals = [10, 20]
rects1 = baxes.bar(ind, yvals, width, color='r')
zvals = [15, 35]
rects2 = baxes.bar(ind+width, zvals, width, color='g')

baxes.set_ylim([0, 100])

baxes.set_ylabel('Y')
baxes.set_xlabel('X')
baxes.set_xticks(ind+width/2)

baxes.set_xticklabels( ('A', 'B') )
baxes.legend( (rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('M', 'N') )

def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        h = rect.get_height()
        baxes.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*h, '%{}'.format(int(h)),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

plt.show()
```

But it throws:

```
AttributeError: 'BarContainer' object has no attribute 'get_height'
```

How can one resolve this issue?

Comment: I have not used this library, so I can only offer a little help. First, the rect to get the height of the bar is a list, unlike matplotlib, so I was able to annotate it correctly by adding a loop to the list. The legend also seems to be affected and gives an error, and the labels for the x-axis are not displayed correctly. The x-axis labeling is also not correct, so the goal of brokenaxes is not being achieved. If you can help me with this, please let me know.

Comment: I have created a code in [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Vukhq5AjBeAvYn-QysmtnmH6xeK4H6eU?usp=sharing) and will share it with you. I will remove it once you confirm.

Comment: I have applied the example from the [official reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html) here to your code. If this is your approach, you are ready to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this library, but I have run Ata's code. The latest version did not work at all with errors, so I dropped the version to 0.4.2. and ran it. I have confirmed the error you mentioned in your question and will respond with a solution. The cause of the error is that rect is a list, so I added a looping process to deal with it.

```
def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
      #print(rect[0])
      for i in range(len(rect)):
        h = rect[i].get_height()
        baxes.text(rect[i].get_x()+rect[i].get_width()/2., 1.05*h, '%{}'.format(int(h)),
              ha='center', va='bottom')
```

However, there are remaining tasks.

- Errors occur in the legend.
- Axis splitting is not realized
- Unnecessary graphs are generated

Due to the current situation, we recommend that you use the axis splitting described in the official matplotlib [reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 2
ind = np.arange(n)  
width = 0.45       

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1, sharex=True, gridspec_kw=dict(height_ratios=[1,4]))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.1)

yvals = [10, 20]
rects1 = ax2.bar(ind, yvals, width, color='r')
zvals = [15,35]
rects2 = ax2.bar(ind+width, zvals, width, color='g')

ax2.set_ylim([0, 40])
ax1.set_ylim([90, 100])
ax2.set_ylabel('Y', loc='top')
ax2.set_xlabel('X')
ax2.set_xticks(ind+width/2)
ax1.set_yticks([90,100])
ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(0,41,10))

ax1.spines.bottom.set_visible(False)
ax2.spines.top.set_visible(False)
ax1.xaxis.tick_top()
ax1.tick_params(labeltop=False)
ax2.xaxis.tick_bottom()

ax2.set_xticklabels( ('A', 'B') )
ax1.legend( (rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('M', 'N') )

def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        h = rect.get_height()
        ax2.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*h, '%{}'.format(int(h)),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

d = .5  # proportion of vertical to horizontal extent of the slanted line
kwargs = dict(marker=[(-1, -d), (1, d)], markersize=12,
              linestyle="none", color='k', mec='k', mew=1, clip_on=False)
ax1.plot([0, 1], [0, 0], transform=ax1.transAxes, **kwargs)
ax2.plot([0, 1], [1, 1], transform=ax2.transAxes, **kwargs)

plt.show()
```

[image]